# Duplicate message may incite making more duplicates

Tags: feature-request

I were stumbling through a question that was marked as a duplicate when I saw this warning and though it did not make much sense:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, **please ask a new question**.

It did not explain the person had to explain why none of the answers in the duplicated questions could address the reason. Also it simply incited the 2nd person to make another duplicate!

It should instead be changed to:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question ***that describes why the duplicated questions does not solve the issue (or, if the reason isn't clear, just the fact).***

Comment: The message displayed to the user who asked is different to indicate they should edit the question.

Comment: @animuson What I mean is the message displayed to the reader (the 2nd person, in this case).